# Same SMTP server, Microsoft Exchange reaches recipient but sendmail does not

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I debated the question title for a while but I think this about explains the question. Feel free to edit it if someone has a better title.

### Environment:

Microsoft Exchange 2010 and sendmail.

### Problem

All users send e-mail through our Microsoft Exchange 2010 server, which in turn sends e-mail through SMTP via our Internet Service Provider `smtp.our-isp.co.uk`.

All applications send their automatic e-mails (invoices and such) through sendmail on a Linux server, which in turn sends e-mail through SMTP via our Internet Service Provider `smtp.our-isp.co.uk`.

**Configuration:**

```
# "Smart" relay host (may be null)
DSsmtp.our-isp.co.uk
```

However, if a user sends an e-mail (Microsoft Exchange 2010 -> ISP SMTP) it reaches the recipient ok but if an application sends an e-mail (sendmail -> ISP SMTP) it doesn't reach the recipient at all (i.e. it is filtered even before reaching their own mailbox it seems).

This happens on particular recipients but I can never understand why, if the e-mails are being sent in the same method.

Does someone have some suggestions here on what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Check your logs on your Linux server, verify that the ISP is accepting the email for delivery.

If it is, then contact them for the logs on their side - ie, we can't help you.

If it isn't, fix whatever's wrong with your Sendmail server.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with mfinni, you need to track the messages a bit further to determine the point of failure.

First assumption is that you are not receiving any type of NDR (non-delivery report) from the emails that never arrive at the destination correct?

Check the maillog on your Linux server and see if it shows errors for the communications. This is always the first step in trying to determine if it is your server configs causing the issue, or something being returned from the receiving server. Additionally, you can manually test smtp from your Linux server to the smtp relay server to verify proper communications. Sample manual smtp session (< denotes responses from server)

> telnet smtp.our-isp.co.uk 25

<220 Server greeting will be seen here

> ehlo servername

<250 may receive multiple 250 lines depending on available options

> mail from: sendinguser@domain

<250 ok

> rcpt to: recipient@domain

<250 ok

> data

- This next section will not generate any feedback, so you will just hit  for each line and the final line is a period by itself on a line (Note there is an empty line between the subject and the body of the email).

> From: sendinguser@domain 
>   To: recipient@domain
>   Subject: Whatever subject you would like
>   
>   Body of the email goes here, type to your heart's content. 
>   .

Assuming the server accepted the message, you should get a 250 reply with some type of acknowledgement (like "queued for delivery", etc.).

If that all succeeds, then the message may be getting hung up at the ISP, or silently dropped by your ISP (is your linux server IP configured to be allowed to relay through your ISP?) or rejected by the recipient site, etc., etc.

You need to try and narrow down how far your email is making it to then try and get assistance in checking logs from other servers involved for which you will not have access to (which is always the fun part in tracking down an email).

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking it may have to do with some sort of spam protection mechanism.

Do you have SPF or DKIM enabeld on the domain?

To check for SPF record on Linux:

```
$ dig +short example.com txt
```

You should also take a look at your sendmail logs. It's usually something like `/var/log/maillog`:

```
less /var/log/maillog
```

Finally, on the sendmail box, you could try to telnet to the SMTP server of your ISP and see what kind of response you get. An example:

```
$ telnet.exe smtp.example.com 25
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to smtp.example.com (192.168.1.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp.example.com ESMTP service ready
> EHLO me.example.com
250 smtp.example.com  Hello
> MAIL FROM: me@example.com
250 ok
> MAIL TO: you@other.example.com
250 ok
> DATA
354 Start mail input; end with .
> From: me@example.com
> To: you@other.example.com
> Subject: Test message now
> 
> Test message.
> .
250 2.6.0  queued mail for delivery

> quit
```

E-mail could be very complicated. The ISP may drop the message without giving you any indication as to why. If all these steps to narrowing down the problem fail, your last resort would be to contact them directly.